# An Implicit CartesianProduct get created in the Apace Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have three joins in the sparksql (TableA ,TableB and TableC ) with there primarykeys. On execution this join creates two types of plan.

- Plan 1 - Which is not having a cartesian product and complete  within Seconds
- Plan 2 - Which implicitly creates a CartesianProduct which run for long until the query time out.

We are not sure why we have two plans and how the second plan is chosen by the spark planner.

Can someone help with  how to get rid of the plan 2.

Note :   No explicit CartesianProducts are in the query.

[image]

We ensured that there are no joins which creates  cartesianProduct .All the joins are performed by joining the primary key

Comment: Are you using the Unity catalog in databricks?

Comment: perhaps a non-relevant question but why is END_DATE getting cast to string then to date?  START_DATE doesn't seem to need that.

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula no we are not using unity catalog in databricks

Comment: Can you provide me the code

Comment: Sorry code can't be  provided. but the interesting thing is spark mostly create plan 1 ..its unable to replicate and Plan 2 is happening randomly ( without any pattern)

Comment: Because of your join conditions (only >= and <=) Spark's choices of how to execute it are limited to cartesian- or broadcast-nested-loop. You can follow Spark's logic by looking at [SparkStrategies.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala#L138) source. You can try to "hint" it to use another join algo but BNLJ will probably be even slower.

Comment: @mazaneicha There is no explicit join condition( >= and <= ) Instead with the same column we are explicitly  giving the condition to pickup delta data and for historical reload (watermark_column between start_Date and end_Date )